# GET entire div with its elements and send it with php mail function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make an function for users to send an e-mail, the e-mail should contain only 1 div from the page(note: that div has elements previously added with the jquery drag and clone function). I dont have an idea how to copy the entire div with its child elements and add them into a hidden field so that I could later send thim with POST method and then send that with e-mail function. Any ideas and recommendations?

**Thank you for your time and help**

Comment: `$('#divid').text();` or `$('#divid').html();` will get you the source ... `$('#hiddenid').val(valuefromabove);` would set it

Comment: Since you say you are using jQ this is very easy - just do `var theHTML = '<div>'+$('#idOfDiv').html().'</div>';`

Comment: Is it necessary to copy the entire div, or do you really want the values of elements _within_ the div?

Comment: Be warned that most email clients (including Outlook 2007, Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo Mail, etc) render a very limited set of HTML and CSS elements. i.e. Although you can send it, the HTML may end up looking terrible as an email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say for example your html is something like

```
<div id="email-data">
    <div id="content">
        some Data Here
    </div>
</div>
<a id="sendEmail" >Send Email</a>
```

you can use jquery to select the div and send data through ajax to a php file and then send email from that file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#sendEmail').click(function(){
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'sendEmail.php',
         data: { content: $('#email-data').html()}
     });
  });

});
```

And in the back end you could probably check for $_POST['content'] (say im using php) and modify your logic accordingly . Here's the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7zk2/) code

Comment: I tried this but it wont get the information with $_POST['data']! here is the project: arbamedia.com/test this is the me_sukses.php page: <?php echo $_POST['data'];

Comment: something is not working I think the problem is with the .click function

Comment: If you are dynamically adding the buttton , you need to use "live instead of "click", so the function will change to $('#sendEmail').live('click',function(){...});

Comment: Maybe I am missing something I dont know, it just doesnt work! I tried to find the problem but nothing..

Comment: Could you be more specific, Is it the ajax that is not working, or a js error or is it in the php side. I have updated the code above and the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/h7zk2/1/) .

Comment: I think its about PHP now because In the debugging console I testet it and it worked, the POST PARAMETER has this: <div id="content"> some Data Here </div> which means it worked, but when I try to test it in the sendEmail.php with this code: 

if (isset($_POST['content'])) {
echo 'yes';
}else {
echo 'no';
}

It echoes "no"

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a form with id `mail`, and hidden input with id `content` and name `content`, and submit button.

Also, you have div, where you manipulate all your entire content, with id `mail-body`.

Then, this code will preprocess data before submitting, and while preprocessing puts all content from working `$('div#mail-body')` into hidden field `content`.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Live means that if the html were loaded via AJAX, this trigger will also work.
    $('form#mail').live('submit', function(e) {
        $(this).find('input[type="hidden"]#mail-body').val($('div#content').html());
    });
});
```

Then you've got on a server side everything that were in `$('div#content')` in post/get var named `$_POST['content']` or `$_GET['content']`.

Answer (score 2):

If i think i've understood you correctly

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var html = $('#divID').html();
$('#divID').hide();

//when you want to send it to php
  $.ajax(function{
    type="POST",
    url:"email.php",
    data:"data="+html,
    success:function(response){
       $('#divID').show().html("email sent");
    }
  });

});
```

get the data on the other side with $_POST['data']